# OGR update using case statement

Tags: ogr, update, sqlite

I am looking at updating a number of large shapefiles using ogrinfo and UPDATE. I would like to perform a CASE function to update specific fields with specific values. Is it possible to perform CASE functions within ogrinfo UPDATE?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ryan,
You should be able to with the SQLite dialect:

```
$ ogrinfo -ro -geom=no -where "TZID='America/Boise' OR TZID='America/Denver'" tz_world.shp tz_world
INFO: Open of `tz_world.shp'
  using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: tz_world
Metadata:
DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=2012-06-25

Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 3
Extent: (-179.999900, -89.999900) - (179.999900, 83.627419)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
TZID: String (30.0)
OGRFeature(tz_world):1611
  TZID (String) = America/Boise

OGRFeature(tz_world):3379
  TZID (String) = America/Denver

OGRFeature(tz_world):3380
  TZID (String) = America/Denver
```

Run the case query with `-dialect sqlite`

```
$ ogrinfo -sql "UPDATE tz_world SET TZID=CASE WHEN TZID='America/Boise' THEN 'KYLE' WHEN TZID='America/Denver' THEN 'KYLE2' END" tz_world.shp -dialect sqlite

INFO: Open of `tz_world.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
```

Changes:

```
$ ogrinfo -ro -where "TZID LIKE 'KYLE%'" tz_world.shp  tz_world -geom=no
INFO: Open of `tz_world.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: tz_world
Metadata:
  DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=2015-10-15
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 3
Extent: (-179.999900, -89.999900) - (179.999900, 83.627419)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
TZID: String (30.0)
OGRFeature(tz_world):1611
  TZID (String) = KYLE

OGRFeature(tz_world):3379
  TZID (String) = KYLE2

OGRFeature(tz_world):3380
  TZID (String) = KYLE2
```