# Update shapefile using SQL

Tags: qgis, shapefile, sql

Is it possible to execute raw SQL in QGIS in order to update a shapefile layer?

Lets say I have a layer called 'lamp_posts' imported into my project. I need to make a series of trivial updates, and since I know SQL well, I would prefer to execute SQL expressions similar to the one below. Either by pasting in such expressions, or by loading the SQL from a file.

```
UPDATE lamp_posts
SET lumen = 1500, color = 4000
WHERE type = 'Philips';
```

How about other types of layers (non-shape)?

Comment: At least you can do that with ogrinfo `ogrinfo -dialect SQLite -sql "UPDATE lamp_posts SET lumen=1500..." lamp_posts.shp`.

Comment: You can use [Execute SQL](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#execute-sql) from processing toolbox. But since this is not available as [Edit features in place processing tool](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#the-processing-in-place-layer-modifier) **you can not `update` your file** directly. Instead you have to create a new file.

Comment: Full example of using ogrinfo for updating in place https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166689/ogr-update-using-case-statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can:

1. Convert your shapefile to a geopackage
2. add a connection to it in Browser
3. and use DB Manager:

[image]

Comment: You can use SQL in DB Manager without having to convert from a shapefile. i.e. there is no need to convert the shapefile.

Comment: @Oisin: If you could post an answer with full instructions that would be greatly appreciated.